# Matrix in Python That Can Represent Items on a Shelf

Tags: python, matrix, data-structures

My question is pretty straightforward. Is there a library in Python that has a data structure that can represent items on a shelf? Essentially, it would need to be a matrix where each row is the same length but the items in each row can be of varying lengths.

Here's a visual representation:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: what? sounds like just lists of lists would be fine

Comment: In python you can make lists of object. Make a class for your shelf objects and just use a normal list

Comment: If you are going to be instantiating each item on your own and the number of spaces is limited, then a list of lists would suffice. Otherwise, think about a dataframe with `NaN` for empty slots on the shelves.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the empty spots. I'm concerned about being able to compare items on shelves above and below each other. For example, if an item on the top shelf is 50 units long and 2 items directly below it are 25 units long each, I want to be able to make the statement that both of those items are directly underneath.

Comment: Could you use `numpy.array` and treat all empty spots as items with length 0? That way you can use their nice syntax and math options

Comment: How do I add a length attribute to items in a numpy array?

Answer (score 1):

This should tell you if two shelf items overlap on the shelves (in the sense that one is below or above the other).... Assuming you know where your shelf items are by index.

```
class Item(list):
    pass

shelves = [
    [Item([1, 2,        3,        4]) ,Item([5,          6 ])],
    [Item([7, 8]),Item([9]),Item([10,        11]), Item([12])]
]

# shelf items are indexed by two indices, shelf and item
def shelf_items_overlap(shelves, shelf1, item1, shelf2, item2):
    item1_real_index = sum(map(len, shelves[shelf1][:item1]))
    item2_real_index = sum(map(len, shelves[shelf2][:item2]))
    return range_overlaps(
         item2_real_index, item2_real_index + len(shelves[shelf2][item2]),
         item1_real_index, item1_real_index + len(shelves[shelf1][item1])
    )

def range_overlaps(x11,x12,x21,x22):
    ''' return if (x11, x12) overlaps (x21, x22) '''
    return x21<=x12<=x22 or x21<=x11<=x22 or x11<=x21<=x12 or x11<=x22<=x12

print(shelf_items_overlap(shelves, 0, 1, 1, 0), shelf_items_overlap(shelves, 0, 1, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My issue is that, each item in a row may not take up the same length. As per the diagram in the link above, items within a row can be different lengths but each row is the same length.

Comment: That is precisely the setup here.  Check out the `shelves` example on the top line.

Comment: I'm assuming that the length of an item is determined by how many things it contains.  What does item "length" mean to you?

Comment: Actually, this code doesn't assume that the shelves are the same length, only that everything is pushed flush to the left, which happens to include the use case where they are all the same length.

Comment: @CharlieMitchell I added an `Item` class to make the code a little more self-descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem should make a better use of classes than arrays. I know that this maybe this is not the answer you're looking but here is a quick code of a class implementation of items and shelf_rows that gets you the info of what it is in a shelf.

```
class Item ():
    # Init the item class with a lenght 
    def __init__(self, length, name = 'Item'):
        self.name = name
        self.length = length
    # Allow us to use the len method on item to get the length
    def __len__(self):
        return self.length
    # Show us a clear print of the Item
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%r of length (%r)' % (self.name,self.length)

class ShelfRow ():
    #Make a ShelfRow of a fixed length
    def __init__ (self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.space_left = length
        self.items = []
    #Use append like if it was a list
    def append (self,Item):
        if Item.length > self.space_left:
            return 'This should throw an error because the length is too long for the space left'
        else:
            self.items.append (Item)
            self.space_left = self.space_left - Item.length
    # Use the __getitem__ special method to get the position of an item
    def __getitem__(self,position):
        return self.items[position]
    #Print the content of items
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%r' % self.items

# Make three items
item_a = Item(4, 'Big Box')
item_b = Item(2, 'Medium Box')
item_c = Item(2, 'Medium Box')
item_d = Item(8, 'Super Big Box')

#Make a shelfRow
shelf_row1 = ShelfRow(8)
shelf_row2 = ShelfRow(8)

#Populate shelfs
shelf_row1.append(item_a)
shelf_row1.append(item_b)
shelf_row1.append(item_c)
shelf_row2.append(item_d)

#Make a shelf, it could be an object too (it should probably)
shelf = [shelf_row1,shelf_row2]

#Print what is in every shelf_row
for shelf_row in shelf:
    print(shelf_row)
```

The other answer is probably the closest to what you want but I get the feeling that maybe you could do for something a little more abstract to solve your problem.

Anyways I hope that this was useful.

Comment: also with ShelfRow you can get the items with [] (shelf_row1[0] gets you item_a)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any module, but this seems like a traditional "Make this data structure" type of question. So here's a base you can work with, and it may seem similar to other questions, but this should work and satisfy your needs. Its pretty much an implementation that uses the idea used in page allocation as your problem can be seen as you need frame to contain a certain amount of pages of a fixed size. It could be optimized by using a better algorithm (or process to add) but I forgot which one I used is called nor did I feel like implementing something more complicated.

```
class Item:
    def set_width(self, width):
        self.width = width

    def get_width(self):
        return self.width

    def __init__(self, width=0):
        self.width = width

class Shelf:
    def add_item(self, item):
        if item.get_width() > self.max_width:
            print("Item will not fit in the shelf.")
            return False

        row = 0
        while (row < len(self.rows)):
            if (self.get_row_tot(row) + item.get_width()) <= self.max_width:
                self.rows[row].append(item)
                return True
            row += 1

        # Stop here, we want to prevent addition of a shelf
        if max_height != -1 and row >= max_height:
            print("Item will not fit in the shelf.")
            return False

        self.rows.append([item])
        return True

    def get_row_tot(self, row):
        tot = 0
        for i in self.rows[row]:
            tot += i.get_width()
        return tot


    def remove_item(self, row, item):
        if row < len(self.rows):
            self.rows[row].remove(item)
            return True
        else:
            print("Row does not exist")
            return False

    def __init__(self, max_width, max_height=-1):
        """
        max_height = -1 means no height limit
        """
        self.max_width = max_width
        self.max_height = max_height
        self.rows = []
        self.head = 0


a = Shelf(3)
b = Item(1)
c = Item(1)
d = Item(2)
e = Item(2)

a.add_item(b)
a.add_item(c)
a.add_item(d)
a.remove_item(0, c)
a.remove_item(2, e)
a.add_item(e)
```

Like I said, this could be optimized and some additions could be made such as a method to swap, set, search, sort and so on so forth. You can also modify Item to be an object you're working with.